# Problem in APIRest file throught GET in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to do my first API Rest and I am following some tutorials. I am requesting all the articles in a MongoDB database.

This is the code of the main:

```
var express  = require("express"),
app      = express(),
http     = require("http"),
bodyParser  = require("body-parser"),
methodOverride = require("method-override"),
server   = http.createServer(app),
mongoose = require('mongoose');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride());

// Import Models and controllers

var models     = require('./models/article')(app, mongoose);
var articleCtrl = require('./controllers/articleController');

// Example Route

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send("Hello world!");
});

articles.route('/articles/:id')
  .get(articleCtrl.findById);

  articles.route('/articles')
  .get(articleCtrl.findAllarticles)
  .post(articleCtrl.addarticle);

app.use('/api', articles);
app.use(router);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/ustcg', { useNewUrlParser: true ,useUnifiedTopology: true}, function(err, res) {
  if(err) {
    console.log('ERROR: connecting to Database. ' + err);
  }
  app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Node server running on http://localhost:3000");
  });
});
```

The code of the controller is here:

```
// Import article and mongoose

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Article  = mongoose.model('Article');

//GET - Return a article with specified ID
exports.findById = function(req, res) {
    Article.findById(req.params.id, function(err, Article) {
    if(err) return res.send(500, err.message);

    console.log('GET /article/' + req.params.id);
        res.status(200).jsonp(Article);
    });
};

//GET - Return all articles in the DB
exports.findAllarticles = function(req, res) {
    Article.find(function(err, Article) {
    if(err) res.send(500, err.message);

    console.log('GET /article')
        res.status(200).jsonp(Article);
    });
};

//POST - Insert a new article in the DB
exports.addarticle = function(req, res) {
    console.log('POST');
    console.log(req.body);

    var Article = new Article({
        title:          req.body.title,
        paragraphs:     req.body.paragraphs
    });

    Article.save(function(err, Article) {
        if(err) return res.send(500, err.message);
    res.status(200).jsonp(Article);
    });
};
```

The model:

```
//We create the model 

exports = module.exports = function(app, mongoose) {

    var ArticleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        title:            { type: String },
    paragraphs:       { type: Array },
    });

    mongoose.model('Article', ArticleSchema);

};
```

When I tried to request the following http request it send me 404 error. I can not see any logs on the console so it is not entering the methods in order to see the exception is happening so I am stucked with this...

If someone could help me it would be nice.

Comment: What is your url requesting?

Comment: GET http://localhost:3000/articles

Comment: you need to put articles/:id  after articles route. actually the routes are based on regular expression and your articles is matched with articles/:id and it's missing id. That's why it is giving error 404.

Answer (score 0):

what is `articles` variable in your main file.
I tried your code in my machine and struggled with articles variable and you have extra imports which are not required. 
Try following code it works fine

```js
var express  = require("express");
var app      = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var articleCtrl = require('./sample.controller');

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send("Hello world!");
});

router.get('/articles/:id', articleCtrl.findById);

router.post('/articles', articleCtrl.addarticle);
router.get('/articles', articleCtrl.findAllarticles)

// app.use('/api', router);
app.use(router);

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Node server running on http://localhost:3000");
});
```

if you uncomment `app.use('/api', router);` then you can also use routes as `localhost:3000/api/articles`